# Remove AndroidStatusBar in Expo react-native

Tags: react-native, expo

The problem is:

`"androidStatusBar": { "hidden": true },`

androidStatusBar is not working in the splash screen of the Expo project. How can I set androidStatusBar in app.json for the Expo project?

I got the same request for the expo-navigation-bar before. This is how I solved this problem:

`"plugins": [ [ "expo-navigation-bar", { "position": "absolute", "visibility": "hidden", "behavior": "inset-swipe", "backgroundColor": "#00000080" } ],...`

But expo-status-bar is not a supported plugins.

I'm trying to get the androidStatusBar property to work on the splash screen page in the expo project.